# Cannot create AWS glue crawler in a Lambda, Lambda is triggered by a Step function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-step-functions

This is my scenario:

1. API gateway/Lambda triggers a Step function. The payload to the step function is a SQL query to run on an existing Athena table
2. Task-1 of Step function calls StartQueryExecution API on Athena.
   The query runs successfully and generates results in a given S bucket
3. Task-2 invokes a Lambda which creates an AWS crawler based on the results from Task-2 (Task-2 gets the S3 file location as input from Task-1)
4. Task-3 invokes a Lambda that runs the crawler that is created in Task-2

[image]

To create AWS crawler in Lambda, following is my code in Lambda (NodeJS):

```
  exports.handler = async(event) => {
    const awsglue = new aws.Glue();

    const uuid = event.QueryExecutionID
    var path = event.OutputPath

    var params = {
        Name: uuid,
        Role: <Role ARN>,
        DatabaseName: <Database name>,
        Targets: {
            S3Targets: [{
                Path: path
            }]
        }
    }

   var request = await awsglue.createCrawler(params, (err, data) => {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
   else console.log(data);
    })
  
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(uuid),
    };
    return response;
};
```

**Problem**
`createCrawler` being an asynchronous call, Lambda returns SUCCESS, even before the creation of the crawler. Consequently, Task-3, which is supposed to run the crawler, fails.

To work around this problem I tried combining `createCrawler` and `startCrawler` in the same Lambda function but that too doesn't work.

Am I missing something?
Is it not possible to create an AWS Glue crawler in a Lambda function that is triggered by a Step function?

Comment: In theory you can subscribe to clodtrail create crawler event and invoke lambda on it.

Comment: You could list the existing crawlers using the Js SDK from AWS using the ```BatchGetCrawlers ``` and then, based on the response, start the crawler within your next step of your step function (after confirming it was created). I can elaborate more as answer if you think  that is what are you looking for. Also, Is it really necessary to create a crawler everytime you run this pipeline/code? Is this part of an app? What is the context here? cheers.

Comment: @Lucas This makes sense. I can try `BatchGetCrawlers` or `getCrawler` in a task following the `createCrawler` task

Answer (score 2):

The Glue crawler should be created with the state machine of Step Functions managed by Infra as code, like CloudFormation, Terraform and AWS CDK.

Then the lambda func start the crawler and retrieve the result of crawler’s run.

See the similar sample code,

Lambda Func to start crawler, https://github.com/awslabs/realtime-fraud-detection-with-gnn-on-dgl/blob/61b341eb1fed1b1b471c9fdccce0c348ff7f343f/src/lambda.d/crawl-data-catalog/index.ts#L24-L37

Create crawler by CDK, https://github.com/awslabs/realtime-fraud-detection-with-gnn-on-dgl/blob/61b341eb1fed1b1b471c9fdccce0c348ff7f343f/src/lib/etl-glue.ts#L78-L95

Comment: I have a doubt (this is me trying to learn more about the aws Js SDK). Don't you think it would work as well just check if the crawler was sucessfully created before pass to the next task of the step function? (listing the existing crawlers and checking the response would be an idea). I said this because this is what I have done it with Boto3. Also, why manage the states of the Step function with IaC? You mean create the state machine using Terraform, Serverless or Cloudformation? Just to confirm, tks!

Comment: Yes. The Glue crawler and state machine of Step Functions are AWS resources you can manage them via IaC code using CloudFormation/Terraform/CDK.

Comment: In my case, a user runs an ad-hoc query on an existing Athena table. To visualize the results of this query in Amazon QuickSight, we need a table in Athena. Therefore, we are trying to create a crawler on the fly

Comment: It makes scene for your case.